# How can I import by "@"?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, es6-modules

I use npm to install modules in a virtual environment.like "npm install vue"
my "node_modules" have @vue and vue
package.json have

```
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.3.4"
  }
```

I tried

```
import '@vue'
```

but failed

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

if I want use "@" to import module,what's the right way?

Comment: The package name is `"vue"` so you have to `import {} from "vue"`. Why do you want to add an @? I don't see any good reason to do it.

Comment: sorry,this may be my mistake, I want to know how to import a module without using a path after I install it.
I try import Vue from 'vue' but it failed

Comment: This is XY problem. If you have problems with `import Vue from 'vue'`, you need to ask about that. This totally depends on your project, so this needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve